# Javascript Json parse data into html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to parse into html the json however I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Would you guys be able to help me to fix this?

It would eventually go on a table.

Great to have an understanding here of what I'm doing wrong.

I know there are plenty of posts regarding json parse, but I can't find a way to display this type of json?

looking like [![enter image description here][1]][1]

```js
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
      callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}

//usage:
readTextFile("https://assets.cmcmarkets.com/json/cmc-test-most-popular-feed.json", function(text) {
  var data = JSON.parse(text);
  //console.log(data);



  var obj = JSON.parse(text, function(key, value) {


    const name = value == "name",
      code = document.querySelector('.code'),
      spread = document.querySelector('.spread');
    cellA = document.querySelector('.cellA');
    cellA.innerHTML = key;

    // name.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["name"]}</div>`;
    // code.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["code"]}</div>`;
    // spread.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["spread"]}</div>`;
    // cellA.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["1day"]}</div>`;

    if (value == "name") {
      document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${data[key]["name"]}</div>`;
    }

    if (value == "1day") {
      cellA.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["movement"]}</div><div>price: ${data[key]["price"]}</div>`;
    }
    console.log(key);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="name"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="spread"></div>
<div class="cellA"></div>
```

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.name')` selects the first element with a class of "name" but your divs only have ids. I think you want `document.querySelector('#name')`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')` Your  selector is wrong, it should be `'#cellA'`, not `'.cellA'`

Comment: @JeremyThille thank, sorry I forgot to update the html in there. Yes, even with that change is not pulling through the right data into html

Comment: @user1599011 thanks, stupidly I forgot to change the id into class. Still though doesn't work

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar  Trying to display the json datas into html

Answer (score -1):

It should be `if(key == "1day")`, not `if(value == "1day")`.
But then you immediately get another error, because  `data['1day']` is undefined (it should be `data["X-ABFDN"]['1day']` or `data["X-ABAAA"]['1day']` or `data["X-AQWER"]['1day']`)

```js
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
      callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}

//usage:
readTextFile("https://assets.cmcmarkets.com/json/cmc-test-most-popular-feed.json", function(text) {
  var data = JSON.parse(text);
  // console.log(data);

  var obj = JSON.parse(text, function(key, value) {
    const name = value == "name",
      code = document.querySelector('.code'),
      spread = document.querySelector('.spread');
    cellA = document.querySelector('.cellA');
    cellA.innerHTML = key;

    // name.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["name"]}</div>`;
    // code.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["code"]}</div>`;
    // spread.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["spread"]}</div>`;
    // cellA.innerHTML = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["1day"]}</div>`;

    console.log(`key='${key}', value='${value}'`);

    if (key == "name") {
      document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${data[key]["name"]}</div>`;
    }

    if (key == "1day") {
      const html = `<div>movement: ${data[key]["movement"]}</div><div>price: ${data[key]["price"]}</div>`;
      console.log("html=" + html);
      cellA.innerHTML = html;
    }
    console.log(key);
  });
});
```

```css
.cellA {
  border: red dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name"></div>
<div class="code"></div>
<div class="spread"></div>
<div class="cellA"></div>
```

Comment: thanks but there are still few errors there

Comment: looks like the name always goes on cellA? also should display the value of it!

Comment: Well yeah you wrote `cellA.innerHTML = key`. So it's "name". Then the script crashes because `data['name']` is undefined, so nothing changes. That's another problem, if you can't solve it either, please open another question.